# When exactly is a Callable passed to an ExecutorService available for garbage collection

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection, executorservice, callable

I have a thread pool of 8 and I am giving it approximately 100 instances of class implementing `Callable` i.e. `WorkerThread`

```
for (List<String> s : listOfLists) {
    Future<?> future = executor.submit(new Worker(hugeList));   
}

for (Future<?> f : futures) {
        try {
            String result = (String) f.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error("Interrupted", e);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            logger.error("Execution exception", e);
        }
    }


            executor.shutdown();
```

When will the instances passed to the executor be eligible for garbage collection? As soon as the f.get() is executed are they eligible for garbage collection or all the `new Worker(hugeList)` will remain in memory until the `executor.shutdown()` is called.

Every `new Worker()` is really big and I would them to be garbage collected after their respective thread is executed. But I am not sure when they are eligible for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the result of the callable references the callable itself, as soon as the task is executed, it's not referenced by anything, and thus becomes eligible to GC.

A pool is a queue where tasks wait to be executed, and a set of threads taking them out of the queue and executing them. Once executed, the pool doesn't care about the tasks anymore, and doesn't keep them anywhere.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @NickDiv "Unless the result of the callable references the callable itself" can you please elaborate this? a callable returns a Future<T> right so i am a little confused

Comment: @JayD It just means that unless the callable instance is not  referenced after it finishes execution. It returns Future but if the result i.e. Future.get() does not hold any reference to the Callable instance it should be eligible for garbage collection